# Connect Oracle DB using Sqlplus with default the SID

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I am having 1 DB server and 1 app server, I would like to connect db server from app server using `sqlplus` client. And the Database has two different database instances.

I've configured my `TNSnames.ora` in `sqlplus` client which sitting in app server, and I am  using script below to connect to DB server and it works :

```
sqlplus username/password@SID
```

Now I have a requirement  to set the SID such that it depends on the user ID logged in linux. I've tried to export the `ORACLE_SID` to the SID I would like to connect:

```
export ORACLE_SID=mySID
sqlplus username/password
```

And I got this error:

> invalid username/password

The reason of it, I believe, that I didn't connect to the right instances. How can I set that SID environment based on User login in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and in case for other people reference: 
in Linux, set the variable `TWO_TASK` to the alias that you would like to configure.

For example as below:

```
export TWO_TASK=alias2
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your example is showing really. All you need to do is export ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_BASE and ORACLE_SID. This can be stored in each user's ~/.bash_profile (or whatever shell you're using).

Comment: @bobdylan Of course u can export those. However, ORACLE_SID only applied to LOCAL DB , not REMOTE DB. If u needs to connect DB server from App server, ORACLE_SID wont help u in this case.

Comment: So you're not doing @ SID and you're acutually doing @ TASK_TWO where TASK_TWO is some remotedb name as defined in the tnsnames. That makes more sense.